# How do I store encrypted env variables in Altostra ENV?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-sns, altostra

I have an Altostra project with a Lambda function that listens on SNS topic, and needs to call another service using an API Token. I need to save the API Key as an env variable, how do I keep it encrypted?
Could anybody help me with that?
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to store sensitive data in an env variable, because it will be exposed to anyone who can access the Lambda.
A better option is to store the API key in a SSM parameter. [AWS SSM is a secured storage for sensitive data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

You can add a SSM parameter reference to an Altostra project and use it in the Lambda like so:

1. Add a parameter to SSM in AWS web console (Type = SecureString).
2. Add a SSM resource and the parameter name of the API key:
   [image]
3. Connect the Lambda to the SSM resource:
   [image]
4. In the Lambda code, import SSM from aws-sdk, and call ssm.getParameter() in order to use the api-key:

```html
import { SSM } from 'aws-sdk';
const ssm = new SSM();

const param = await ssm.getParameter({
          Name: 'api-key',
          WithDecryption: true,
        }).promise();
```